# .gitignore fails to ignore files not previously cached

Tags: git, version-control

I have a `.gitignore` file (made with `vim` on linux) in my repository's directory witht the following contents:

```
# Data files
*.txt
```

When I add any `*.txt` file to this repository, in the same directory as the `.gitignore`, it lists it as un-tracked and becomes tracked when I do a `git add .`

What's the deal? This is the same for other repositories with other file types.

**Update**

Trying a `file .gitignore` (on the command line) showed that I had the correct line endings:

```
.gitignore: ASCII text
```

Trying a `:set list` (in `vim`) showed that I DID have trailing whitespace:

```
# Data files$
*.txt $
```

Comment: What are you using to create the .gitignore file?

Comment: I am using `vim` to create it.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is trailing whitespace or the wrong line endings.

Comment: it was the trailing whitespace. man that was driving me crazy. do you want to put that into an answer so I can select it? thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check for trailing whitespace after patterns as this can cause Git to ignore them.